# volume slider in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am Creating Volume slider from my music Player for windows 8 but it throw exception saying:

`'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

my code :

```
<Slider x:Name="VolumeSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,563,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" RenderTransformOrigin="0.467,-0.833" ValueChanged="ChangeMediaVolume" />
```

and

```
    // Change the volume of the media.
    private void ChangeMediaVolume(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> args)
    {

        {
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Volume = (double)VolumeSlider.Value;
        }
    }

    void InitializePropertyValues()
    {
                    BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Volume = (double)VolumeSlider.Value;
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Does the Exception specify which Argument / is there an `InnerException`? Additionally, which line of code is the one that is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 6):

You don't set the range of the Slider. The default range is from 0 to 10, however `BackgroundAutoPlayer.Instance.Volume` needs values between 0 and 1, with the default value being 0.85, as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Use this

```
<Slider x:Name="VolumeSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,563,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" RenderTransformOrigin="0.467,-0.833" Maximum="1" ValueChanged="ChangeMediaVolume" />
```

And maybe you would want to set `SmallChange="0.01"` and `LargeChange="0.1"`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Its working fine.Im Stuck with one more thing that is song progress slider can u suggest how to create song progress bar and how to display the duration of song

Comment: but how to make my volume slider to move or change value when phone volume button is pressed.

Comment: Open a new question for that since it has nothing to do with your original one.